# How use wp_insert_post and add og:custom tags?

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development

I need to pass dynamic data to FB and twitter (it's name generator website)
title , picture and description could be different (due website functionality)
As a solution I see that I can create new post and send og tags to it

Answer (score 0):

You can add it this way, you send the tags separated by commas.

```
 // text add
 $my_post = array();
 $my_post['post_title'] = 'title';
 $my_post['post_content'] = 'text.';
 $my_post['post_status'] = 'publish';
 $my_post['post_author'] = 1;
 $my_post['post_category'] = array(8,39);

  //database add
  wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```